# Select Query- exclude holidays count from a totaldays count obtain from date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a project table having field as `name,startdate,enddate`,
using `datediff` I calculated totaldays and then filter sundays as colname `TotalDay_sundayremoved`.

I have another table as holidays , now have to filter these holidays over TotalDay_sundayremoved column

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE holiday_hd (
      date_hd DATETIME
    , enent_hd VARCHAR(200)
);
INSERT INTO holiday_hd
VALUES 
    ('2013-03-15 00:00:00.000', 'Aniversry Leave'),
    ('2013-08-15 00:00:00.000', 'Independence Day'),
    ('2014-08-15 00:00:00.000', 'Independence Day');

CREATE TABLE Project_pj (
      Name VARCHAR(200)
    , start_date_pj DATETIME
    , ed_date_pj DATETIME
    , expectedend_date_pj DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO Project_pj
VALUES 
    ('aaa', '2012-12-01 00:00:00.000', '2023-07-22 00:00:00.000', NULL),
    ('bbb', '2012-12-01 00:00:00.000', NULL, '2023-07-22 00:00:00.000'),
    ('ccc', '2013-12-01 00:00:00.000', NULL, '2014-07-22 00:00:00.000'),
    ('ddd', '2013-07-01 00:00:00.000', NULL, '2016-07-22 00:00:00.000');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
      Name
    , start_date_pj
    , ISNULL(ed_date_pj, expectedend_date_pj) AS enddate
    , DATEDIFF(DAY, start_date_pj, ISNULL(ed_date_pj, expectedend_date_pj)) AS No_Days
    , (DATEDIFF(dd, start_date_pj, ISNULL(ed_date_pj, expectedend_date_pj)) + 1)
      - (DATEDIFF(wk, start_date_pj, ISNULL(ed_date_pj, expectedend_date_pj)) * 1)
      - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, start_date_pj) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDay_sundayremoved
FROM Project_pj
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9d9d/1)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
      name
    , start_date_pj
    , enddate
    , No_Days = DATEDIFF(DAY, start_date_pj, enddate) 
    , TotalDay_sundayremoved = (DATEDIFF(dd, start_date_pj, enddate) + 1)
         - (DATEDIFF(wk, start_date_pj, enddate) * 1)
         - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, start_date_pj) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        -- - holidays
    , holidays
FROM (
    SELECT 
          name
        , start_date_pj
        , enddate = ISNULL(ed_date_pj, expectedend_date_pj)
    FROM dbo.Project_pj
) p
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT holidays = COUNT(1)
    FROM dbo.holiday_hd h
    WHERE h.date_hd BETWEEN p.start_date_pj AND p.enddate
) t
```

Also you can write sub-query -

```
SELECT
      name
    , ...
    , holidays = (
        SELECT holidays = COUNT(1)
        FROM dbo.holiday_hd h
        WHERE h.date_hd BETWEEN p.start_date_pj AND p.enddate
      )
FROM (
    SELECT 
          name
        , start_date_pj
        , enddate = ISNULL(ed_date_pj, expectedend_date_pj)
    FROM dbo.Project_pj
) p
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT
      name
    , start_date_pj
    , enddate
    , No_Days = DATEDIFF(DAY, start_date_pj, enddate) 
    , TotalDay_sundayremoved = (DATEDIFF(dd, start_date_pj, enddate) + 1)
         - (DATEDIFF(wk, start_date_pj, enddate) * 1)
         - isSunday
        -- - holidays
    , TotalDay_holidayRmoved = (DATEDIFF(dd, start_date_pj, enddate) + 1)
         - (DATEDIFF(wk, start_date_pj, enddate) * 1)
         - isSunday
         - t.holidays
    , t.holidays
    , currentDays_removeSunday = (DATEDIFF(dd, start_date_pj, GETDATE()) + 1)
                 - (DATEDIFF(wk, start_date_pj, GETDATE()) * 1)
                 - isSunday
    , holidays_currentDateCount= holidays_now

    , Currentday_Removeholiday_RemoveSundays_tilldate= DATEDIFF(dd, start_date_pj,  GETDATE()+1) 
                        -(DATEDIFF(wk, start_date_pj, GETDATE()) * 1)
                        - isSunday
                        - holidays_now
FROM (
    SELECT 
          name
        , start_date_pj
        , enddate = ISNULL(ed_date_pj, expectedend_date_pj)
        , isSunday = CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, start_date_pj) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM dbo.Project_pj
) p
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 
          holidays = SUM(holidays) 
        , holidays_now = SUM(holidays_now)
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              holidays = CASE WHEN h.date_hd BETWEEN p.start_date_pj AND p.enddate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            , holidays_now = CASE WHEN h.date_hd BETWEEN p.start_date_pj AND GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM dbo.holiday_hd h
    ) t
) t
```

Comment: thanks you so much devart, its wroking fine, can you give little explantion also or usefull links,

Comment: `OUTER APPLY` is the part of `T-SQL` syntax. Personally I learned `SQL Server` with books of `Itzik Ben Gan`. Check this link: http://tsql.solidq.com/books/tsqlfund2012/

Comment: need your help, i need to get another column with filter sundays and holidays with a daterange of `current date`  over the result which came from using your query . i tried http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9d9d/10  and got the result can you verify once what am doing is right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35281/discussion-between-satinder-singh-and-devart)

Comment: Its fine sir and thanks for spending your time on my query and make my task easy, have learned many things today

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Good luck :)